# express route to different file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backbone-boilerplate

I am new in express and I am using Backbone Boilerplate also. In case of development, when asking for `/assets/css/index.css` I want to deliver `/public/dist/debug/index.css`.
I've made this:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
switch (env) {
    case 'development':
        app.get('/assets/css/index.css', function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile('public/dist/debug/index.css');
        });
        break;
}
```

But for some reason my page keep getting the incorrect file: `/assets/css/index.css`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, unless you use `express.static()` (which I assume is handling the requests for `/assets/css/index.css`; if not, replace with *'the route that's handling those requests'* :) *before* your route (which would mean that the static middleware would get to handle the request first).

Also, instead of your `switch` statement, you can use [`app.configure`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure):

```
app.configure('development', function() {
  // this code will only run when in development mode
  app.get('/assets/css/index.css', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/dist/debug/index.css');
  });
});

// static middleware after your route
app.use(express.static(...));
```

Comment: I have: app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
Does this mean that I should use:  res.sendfile('dist/debug/index.css'); (without "public")?

Comment: @Naor it depends on your directory structure. I think `res.sendfile` will find files relative to the 'current working directory' (which is usually the directory where you started running the app), unless [you provide a `root` option](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile). But since you were getting a response, but just not the correct one, it meant your custom `app.get` wasn't called at all. Which my answer should fix. If not, you need to provide a bit more context (like your application setup).